# How do you escape tags in django templates?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

As I know if I put

```
{{ var_name }}
```

in django template, it will be parsed as an variable. What should I write if I want the string "{{ var_name }}" displayed in HTML file (not {{ var_name }})?

I'm not quite sure how to describe this question, so I have no idea what key word to search in Google. Thank you.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you could try the string `"\{\{ var_name \}\}"`. You basically escape the {{ and }}.

Comment: @arunkumar: unless Django's doc is out of sync, the template system as it stands has no concept of escaping.  See my answer for more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is called *escaping*.

You can substitute the brackets like this:

`&#123;` instead of `{`

`&#125;` instead of `}`

So, in your HTML code,
`&#123;&#123; var_name &#125;&#125;` 
will output
 `{{ var_name }}`.

And there's also the boring way: [templatetag tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag).

Comment: Is it boring because it shows the designer's intent, or boring because you don't have to look up the HTML escape codes?  Or is it just boring because it is robust?

Comment: It's boring because it's the first thing people get when searching for an answer. Also because it solves the problem in a narrower scope, i.e. only for Django.

Answer (score 4):

If I understand you correctly, you want to output text including literal braces.

This is done using the [templatetag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#templatetag) template tag.

For example, in your case, you will want to put:

```
{% templatetag openvariable %} var_name {% templatetag closevariable %}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `var_name` as a value for (for example) an attribute you do have to use the parentheses. For example:

```
{% for key, value in somedict %}
    <input type="hidden" name="{{ key }}" value="{{value}}" />
{% endfor %}
```